# How to call a widget to write data into an external repository using REST Api

Tags: flutter

in my application I would like to write some information during the navigation into an external repository using RESTAPI call.
I have created a page stateful widget with a FutureBuilder to include where needed, I will pass parameters to this widget time by time.
I use already this external repository and I have created an apiserver to retrieve and write data.
I do not have any error nowhere BUT the widget does not do anything, it looks like it is not called at all.
In the code I print only for debug.

Any suggestion?
There is another simple way to achieve the same result?

I call it from the other pages in this way:
const insertLog("TestData");
Do not worry about the content of the data, it is a test for the moment.

Thanks in advance

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:myproject/src/constants/global.dart';
import 'package:myproject/src/models/db_model.dart';


// Insert Log

Future<Logs> writeLog(String plate) async {
  final response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse('https://js"${plServer}/api/log'),
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
      'date': plate,
      'plate': plate,
      'userid': plate,
      'activity': plate,    }),
  );

  if (response.statusCode == 201) {
    return Logs.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>);
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to insert log.');
  }
}

class insertLog extends StatefulWidget {
  const insertLog(this.plate);
  final String plate;

  @override
  State<insertLog> createState() => _insertLogState();
}

class _insertLogState extends State<insertLog> {
  late Future<Logs> log;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("Plate write log =" + widget.plate);
    log = writeLog(widget.plate);
  }

  String datetime = "";
  String plate = "";
  String userid = "";
  String activity = "";

  Map data = {"datetime": "","plate": "", "userid": "", "activity": ""};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Plate write log =" + widget.plate);
    return  const CircularProgressIndicator();

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is quite easy ... just include this page and call the void inside the code using restApiLog("mytext");

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:passionelease/src/constants/global.dart';
import 'package:passionelease/src/models/faq_model.dart';

// Insert Log

Future<Logs> writeLog(String plate) async {
  final response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse('${plServer}/api/log'),
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
//      'datetime': DateTime.now().toString().substring(0,19),
      // 'date': plate,
      'plate': plate,
      'userid': plate,
      'activity': plate,    }),
  );
  
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print('Posted your data: $plate');  // Added print statement
    return Logs.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>);
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to insert log.');
  }
}

void restApiLog(String plate) {
    print("Plate write log = ${plate}");
    writeLog(plate);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not good practice to just move your function to another page. You should create a new class and move function to inside of it.

**api_service.dart:**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:myproject/src/constants/global.dart';
import 'package:myproject/src/models/db_model.dart';

class ApiService {
  Future<Logs> writeLog(String plate) async {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('https://${plServer}/api/log'),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
        'date': DateTime.now().toString(),
        'plate': plate,
        'userid': 'your_user_id',
        'activity': 'your_activity',
      }),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 201) {
      print('Posted your data: $plate');
      return Logs.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to insert log.');
    }
  }
}
```

**main.dart:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'api_service.dart';

class Logs {
  // Define your Logs class here or import it if it's in a separate file
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Your App Title',
      home: InsertLog('SamplePlate'),  // Pass a sample plate for testing
    );
  }
}

class InsertLog extends StatefulWidget {
  const InsertLog(this.plate);
  final String plate;

  @override
  State<InsertLog> createState() => _InsertLogState();
}

class _InsertLogState extends State<InsertLog> {
  late Future<Logs> log;
  final ApiService apiService = ApiService();  // Create an instance of ApiService

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("Plate write log = ${widget.plate}");
    log = apiService.writeLog(widget.plate);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Insert Log'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<Logs>(
        future: log,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
            );
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: Text('Log inserted successfully!'),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work, no error again but no sign from the console of the call

Comment: Actually this code itself has no syntax or logical error. What do you mean it didn't work?

Comment: yes, no syntax problem, in one of my page I put an hardcoded value to test the functionality, I see the "Before" and "After" log but nothing from inside the insertLog. I call it inside another FutureBuilder, I tried also inside a onTap() icon.

print("Before Insert");
insertLog("HasData");
print("After Insert");

Comment: I created a simple widget, it print a string to the console, I tried it as stateful and stateless, nothing. If I put the same code in the main page it works

  @override
  void initState() {
    print("Test init state");
    super.initState();
  }

if I call the widget from another widget it is not working

Comment: Ok, I described in the wrong way what I would like to do.
Proceeding with my test I create a tab with the page in the solution and it works perfectly, when I select the tab with this page my rest api server is called and it works.
Now, what I want to achieve is to have like a function that I can include in any page and that I can call inside the code to track with an external rest api the process that the end user is doing.
Without changing to another page, just like a void function, that will call the restapi process to insert the new data.
Is it more clear now? Thanks

Comment: Yes understood now. I am editing my response now as you want.